New toilet and piping…1 toilet drains slowly still
Thank you in advance for any help with this
Background: I grew up in this house. All drains work great except the half bath. 2” vent and 3” waste.
I did a bathroom remodel in the full bath and replaced all cast iron waste lines with ABS. Toilets in both bathrooms were replaced.
The half bath toilet still drains slowly and clogs easily as it always has which is baffling.

What are we looking at in the picture? Consider labeling it and replacing the current picture with the labeled one. Have you checked the slope on all the lines? If the ABS replaced the iron just as they were, and the iron lines were not sloped correctly, the ABS lines would have the same problems as the iron lines did.

From appearances, it definitely looks like at least the horizontal ABS run in the background is sloped incorrectly.
